# Evaluate expression of implicit TypeTag on Intellij debugger fails, why? and how can i enable it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, implicit, scala-reflect

```
package spark.course.example

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

object Example extends App{

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("Example").getOrCreate

    import spark.implicits._

    val columns = Seq("language","users_count")

    val data = Seq(("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000"))

    val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(columns:_*)

    val df_with_col = df.withColumn("raw",typedLit[Option[Int]](None))

}
```

I try do debug the last row and evaluate the expression of:
`df.withColumn("raw",typedLit[Option[Int]](None))`
but getting error in the evalution that says
Cannot find local variable 'TypeTag'
Error evaluating method : 'TypeTag': Error evaluating method : 'TypeTag'

Why it can't find it?
How can I make it work so i can debug & evaluate easily?

Thanks

Tried to add `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._;` before the expression in the evaluation window and still it didn't find it

Comment: Probably a bug in IntelliJ debugger. If I manually resolve `df.withColumn("raw", typedLit[Option[Int]](None)(typeTag[Option[Int]]))` then with `import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.universe._` it can't find `ScalaReflection`, with `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._` it throws `ClassNotFoundException`. It eats `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection` but doesn't eat `import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst._; ScalaReflection`. You can try to report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Reported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-314046